# Having some problems understanding why its not slicing my string

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, tdd, slice

```
describe('China UnionPay', function() {
  let expect = chai.expect;

  for (var prefix = 624; prefix <= 626; prefix++) {
    for (let j = 17; j <= 19; j++) {
      let cardNum = `${prefix}7891123456789`;
      (function(prefix) {
        it(`it has a prefix of ${prefix} and a length of ${j}`, function() {
          //  console.log(`${cardNum.slice(0,j)}`)
          console.log('typeof cardNum', typeof cardNum, '    ', 'length of string =>', j, 'card is not the length of j?', cardNum.slice(0, j))

          expect(detectNetwork(cardNum.slice(0, j))).to.equal('China UnionPay');
        })
      })(prefix)
    }
  }
})
```

What I would like this code to do is to take the `cardNum` and slice from `0` to the length of what `j` is currently at. I already added the prefix to the front but not sure why it's not returning a slice portion of `cardNum` and returning the whole thing?

Comment: `cardNum` is 17 characters long, so `cardNum.slice(0, 17)` is the whole string.

Comment: What are you expecting it to be instead of the whole thing?

Comment: im so blind. you guys are helpful thank you! i just have to add more numbers to the string that would be all simple syntax error that i couldnt see thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value of `j` in your code ranges between 17 and 19. While length of your string i.e. 
`var cardNum` is 13 characters + 3 characters of `var prefix`. So basically length of your resulting `cardNum` variable is 16.
Syntax of slice function is `str_name.slice(startPointPosition, endPointPosition);`
And in the code above endPointPosition i.e. value of var j is always greater than total length of `cardNum`.
If you change value of `j` to less than 16 you can see the change.